# How to make each form it's own thread and able to update?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I am have three(4 counting the main one) threads in my application(chat app) and I want to put each form into it's own thread(one thread does not need a form so it is irrelevant). The 2 forms I am working with are clocks with a local digital font included. The problem is that threadb will start and run, but threadc will remain as the text LABEL1 and not change at all to: MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt. I am wondering how to get these threads to work together.

Here is the thread code(creating at beginning of porgram, this is from sub official_start):

```
    threadb = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf form3threadsub)
    threadc = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf form4threadsub)
    threadb.IsBackground = False
    threadc.IsBackground = False
    threadb.Start()
    threadc.Start()
```

Here is the code for the thread subs:

```
    Private Sub form3threadsub()
        Dim first As Boolean = False
        Do
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            If first = False Then
                form3.ShowDialog()

                first = True
            End If
            form3.Label1.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
            form3.Update()
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub form4threadsub()
        Dim first As Boolean = False
        Do
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            If first = False Then
                Form4.ShowDialog()

                first = True
            End If
            Form4.Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
            Form4.Update()
        Loop
    End Sub
```

Here is the button2 click:

```
    Dim clicked As Boolean = True 

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        If clicked Then
            threadb.Suspend()'obsolete
            threadc.Suspend()'obsolete
            Button2.Text = "Resume Clocks"
            clicked = False
        Else
            threadb.Resume()'obsolete
            threadc.Resume()'obsolete
            Button2.Text = "Pause Clocks"
            clicked = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you want to use multithreading - what are you trying to achieve? Have you considered using one thread for the GUI - all forms - and one or more worker threads?

Comment: or even just using timers instead of a loop?

Comment: Also even if you do pause the loop when you resume it will just jump to the current time?

Comment: Yes, if I pause it it does go to the current time. I am trying to do this to allow more work to be done in the main GUI(work relief) and because it is something I want to learn.

Comment: @JoshMentwizzler If you used timers you can do work between events and if that work takes to long then thats what should be on the other threads

Comment: I am not using timers at this time...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my working solution. I took the extra forms out and replaced them with labels on the main form. Each label is it's own thread and updates accordingly.